# Why is my text distantly spaced if i change the format to full justify?

Tags: text, alignment, corel-draw

I'm using Corel Draw X7. I type my word in a text box with left alignment. but when I change it to full justify, the text becomes distantly spaced. And I can't fix it. The text doesn't look neat.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: What kind of layout were you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are telling the program you want the text to fill the width of the text box, no matter what. So when there's too little text, the program must fill the rest with spaces. This is the expected behavior.

The last line in a paragraph should not be justified, so make sure you are using paragraph breaks and not carriage returns. You can check this by enabling non-printing characters and checking that the last character in each block of text is a paragraph sign/pilcrow (¶) and not a carriage return sign (↵ )

Answer (score 0):

**Some software offer you at least 2 different way to "justify" your text.**

One will leave the single lines or last line of a paragraph not justified, and some will justify everything.

Maybe you are having this issue because you,re using the "justify all lines". **You might want to try the fourth icon on the image below**; it will justify the whole paragraph but will leave the single lines or last lines align to the left.

If you don't have that option available (I doubt it), you can always add a "tab" at the end of each line (eg. press the TAB key!). This *is not* a very clean way to make things happen but it works too in some software.

[image: justify text in corel draw]

If this doesn't work, *Spiral* offered the other solutions to fix your issue in her answer!

---

<sup>Image source: jaccore.com</sup>